# Extract all tokens from string using regex in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a string like "httpx://__URL__/__STUFF__?param=value"
This sample is a url by convention...it could be anything with zero or more __X__ tokens in it.

I want to use a regex to extract a list of all the tokens, so output here would be List("__URL__","__STUFF__").  Remember, I don't know beforehand how many (if any) tokens may be in the input string.

I've been struggling but unable to come up with a regex expression that will do the trick.

Something like this did not work:

(?:.*?(__[a-zA-Z0-9]+__).*?)+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala Regex, which is just a wrapper around Java Regex, will never return multiple subgroups for repetitions.

The only way about it is to have a regex for the token, and then find it multiple times. You pretty much already have everything you want:

```
"__[a-zA-Z0-9]+__".r findAllIn "httpx://__URL__/__STUFF__?param=value"
```

That returns an `Iterator`. Use `.toSeq` or similar to convert into a collection.

Comment: Probably you're going to replace the tokens, so `"__([a-zA-Z0-9]+)__".r replaceAllIn (s, _.group(1) match { case "URL" => "myurl" case _ => "other" })`

Comment: @som-snytt Yeah, people ought to ask what their goal is, not how to accomplish a step they imagine they have to go through.

Answer (score 1):

Greg, have you tried a simple

```
_+[^_]+_+
```

This will match all the `__TOKENS__`

It doesn't do any check for any `__TOKENLIKE__` string after the ?params, but you have mentioned you are not only using that for urls. If you need some refinement, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Combine a regex with `split`:

```
def urlPathComponents(s: String): Option[Array[String]] = 
  """(?<=http(s?)://)[^?]+""".r findFirstIn s map (_.split("/"))
```

Comment: That'd only work for urls.  My input string can be almost any string...not just a url.